# BlueZ with BluePy - where does the difference between the specified connection interval values and real connection time come from?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, bluez

I'm trying to use Bluez tool hcitool lecup to setup my bluetooth LE connection interval between 6 (7.6ms BLE min supported value) and 10 (12.5ms).

However, if I then run a bare minimum of my code using BluePy library and poll my BLE compatible sensor, the time it takes to receive the raw data is somewhere in 20ms region, which is almost twice what I would expect.

Has anyone ever come across this discrepancy? What could be the source for it?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your sensor is too slow to respond in the same connection event as your request (it has 150 microseconds). Therefore your response will be sent one connection interval after. Your maximum delay is therefore two times the connection interval.